# How to export a json file from a specific Influxdb database?

Tags: json, database, export, influxdb

I have an influxdb database named `metrics`, I want to export it as a JSON file with its entire data.

```
directory = '/var/lib/influxdb/data'
```

I can save the list of tag keys:

```
influx -execute='show tag keys' -database=metrics -format=json -pretty=true > /home/ivms/metrics.json
```

but how can I save all tags with all values?

Comment: Hi,have you solved this problem?

Answer (score 2):

The query to return all data from all measurements in the database, including both fields and tags, would be:

```sql
SELECT * FROM /.*/
```

The full command line:

```sh
influx -database=metrics -format=json -pretty=true  \
    -execute='SELECT * FROM /.*/'  \
    > ~/metrics.json
```

NOTE:

If your database is complicated (millions of series) you might have to wait a long time for influx to actually respond, in my case it was almost 30min but it worked.

Also Make sure you give the system a large enough swap, to avoid getting OOM killed.

Comment: This must be v1 command set. Doesn't work on current rev.

Comment: Indeed it's been tested on v1.8. I don't have a v2 instance to test on.